# How to get Gentoo Package Count with C Code?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, c, gentoo

I have a terminal fetching program on my GitHub that is similar to Neofetch but it is written in C instead of bash called [Cfetch](https://github.com/Amarakon55/Cfetch)

I know how to get the package count for Arch with C:

```
static char *get_packages(const char* dirname, const char* pacname, int num_extraneous) {
int num_packages = 0;
DIR * dirp;
struct dirent *entry;

dirp = opendir(dirname);

if(dirp == NULL) {
    status = -1;
    halt_and_catch_fire("You may not have %s installed", dirname);
}

while((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
    if(entry->d_type == DT_DIR) num_packages++;
}
num_packages -= (2 + num_extraneous); // accounting for . and ..

status = closedir(dirp);

char *packages = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
snprintf(packages, BUF_SIZE, "%d (%s)", num_packages, pacname);

return packages;
```

}

```
static char *get_packages_pacman_total() {
return get_packages("/var/db/pacman/local", "pacman", 0);
```

}

In Gentoo, packages are each placed in a category unlike Arch. They are located in /var/db/pkg/*/* so I tried this:

```
static char *get_packages_portage_total() {
return get_packages("/var/db/pkg/*", "portage", 0);
```

}

But that didn't work unfortunately. I want to get the total package count and the explicitly installed package count in C, but not sure how. I resorted to using shell code in the program.

To get selected package count:

```
wc -l /var/lib/portage/world | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

To get total package count:

```
ls -d /var/db/pkg/*/* | wc -l
```

Comment: I don't know what you are precisely in a need to achieve. And I suspect you'll need much more than simple counts. Since all that job has already (and seriously) been achieved, I would **strongly** invite you to consider looking for answers to your questions in the q applets (a collection of small, fast Portage query utilities written in C.) All the code is there : https://github.com/gentoo/portage-utils

Comment: Are you actually resolving the glob here? `"/var/db/pkg/*"`

Comment: On the shell I suggest to use `eix -I --only-names | wc -l` with `app-portage/eix`. For C code you can borrow some code from the QApplets https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Q_applets